# Android Test cases not working in debug mode

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I am not able to debug android Instrumentation test cases (using espresso & UiAutomator)

But earlier test cases the debugging was working fine but with recent update it is not working anymore. It gets always struck up at instantiating unit test
[image]

I can see in command window that it's trying to launch PACKAGE_NAME**.test**

```
 adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug true -e class PACKAGE_NAME.LanguageScreenTest#testSelectImportant PACKAGE_NAME**.test**/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Comment: Did you try doing 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' ?

Comment: Yes I did tried 'Invalidate Caches / Restart' and  removing the updated version of studio with older version also did not seems to work (also removed there associated files in system)

Answer (score 2):

The same thing for me in case i use `AndroidOrchestrator`. Turn it off if you dont really need to run the tests with it or, at least, when you want to debug.

*(It has been so long time but just for the others who may fall latterly into this problem)*

Answer (score 2):

As @PhạmLam mentioned, turning off [Android Test Orchestrator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator) worked for me.

To "turn off", I just comment out the `execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'` line in `build.gradle` when I want to debug:

```
...
android {
  defaultConfig {
   ...
   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
 }

  testOptions {
    // Comment out below line
    // execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
}
...
```

Comment: this work, but why can not I use the orchestrator in debug?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with some config file which is not tracked in git (so not able to figure out right now, Will do it when have free time)

> adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e **debug** **true** -e class PACKAGE_NAME.LanguageScreenTest#testSelectImportant PACKAGE_NAME**.test**/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner

when debug parameter is true test cases do not work in debug mode and it will struck on above state

but **when this parameter is false it works**

To solve this problem I have to use another clone of same repository (I had also tried deleting .idea and .gradle in same workspace which did not worked for me)

Comment: meet the same issue, but how to set the `-e debug false`?

Comment: I took a fresh checkout. I did not explored the reason it must be some config file which is not tracked in git