# Android Test cases can only be debugged in debug mode after 10 minutes of waiting

Tags: android, kotlin, testing

It was working before. But now it doesn't anymore. The IDE just shows "Instantiating tests...". But when I wait for 10 minutes, then all of a sudden it does work? The machine is a Macbook Pro, Mid 2015. The problem only occurs on `androidTest`, the `test` directory works fine.

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class SomeTestClass {

    @get:Rule
    var activityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(
            NavigationActivity::class.java, false, false)

    @Before
    fun before() {
        Timber.d("When debugging, this triggers only after about 10 minutes.")
    }

    @Test
    fun testContents() {
        Assert.assertEquals(0, 0)
    }    
}
```

The log keeps outputting this:

```
D/EZIO_NLOG: watchdog_routine executed!
D/EZIO_NLOG: check1 
    check1 
    check2 
    check2
```

Tried the following things:

1. File, Invalidate Cache / Restart
2. Tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034929/android-test-cases-not-working-in-debug-mode). But it seems to be outdated.
3. Edit Configurations..., Selected "All in Package", "Class" and "Method". None of them work.
4. When I wait really long, like 10 minutes, then all of a sudden it triggers and works.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using an emulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

Android Tests are slow and on top of that debugger adds more load to it. I have faced the same problem and I agree that using a debugger with Android Tests is a pain.

Below is something I found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing)
`Espresso detects when the main thread is idle, so it is able to run your test commands at the appropriate time, improving the reliability of your tests.`

and on top of that when a debugger is added it makes it more slow.

You can try running the tests on a real device it should be bit faster(I am assuming)